# Correct use of coroutine in Tornado web server

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I'm trying to convert a simple syncronous server to an asyncronous version, the server receives post requestes and it retrieves the response from an external web service (amazon sqs). Here's the syncronous code

```
def post(self):

    zoom_level = self.get_argument('zoom_level')
    neLat = self.get_argument('neLat')
    neLon = self.get_argument('neLon')
    swLat = self.get_argument('swLat')
    swLon = self.get_argument('swLon')
    data = self._create_request_message(zoom_level, neLat, neLon, swLat, swLon)

    self._send_parking_spots_request(data)

    #....other stuff

def _send_parking_spots_request(self, data):

    msg = Message()
    msg.set_body(json.dumps(data))
    self._sqs_send_queue.write(msg)
```

Reading Tornado documentation and some threads here I ended with this code using coroutines:

```
def post(self):

    zoom_level = self.get_argument('zoom_level')
    neLat = self.get_argument('neLat')
    neLon = self.get_argument('neLon')
    swLat = self.get_argument('swLat')
    swLon = self.get_argument('swLon')
    data = self._create_request_message(zoom_level, neLat, neLon, swLat, swLon)
    self._send_parking_spots_request(data)
    self.finish()

@gen.coroutine
def _send_parking_spots_request(self, data):

    msg = Message()
    msg.set_body(json.dumps(data))
    yield gen.Task(write_msg, self._sqs_send_queue, msg)

def write_msg(queue, msg, callback=None):
    queue.write(msg)
```

Comparing the performances using siege I get that the second version is even worse than the original one, so probably there's something about coroutines and Torndado asyncronous programming that I didn't understand at all.
Could you please help me with this?

**Edit:** `self._sqs_send_queue` it's a queue object retrieved from boto interface and `queue.write(msg)` returns the message that has been written on the queue

Comment: What is the `_sqs_send_queue` in your example? Does that call not return until a response is retrieved from Amazon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tornado` relies on you converting all your I/O to be non-blocking. Simply sticking the same code you were using before inside of a `gen.Task` will not improve performance at all, because the I/O itself is still going to block the event loop. Additionally, you need to make your `post` method a coroutine, and call `_send_parking_spots_requests` using `yield` for the code to behave properly. So, a "correct" solution would look something like this:

```
@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    ...
    yield self._send_parking_spots_request(data)  # wait (without blocking the event loop) until the method is done
    self.finish()

@gen.coroutine
def _send_parking_spots_request(self, data):

    msg = Message()
    msg.set_body(json.dumps(data))
    yield gen.Task(write_msg, self._sqs_send_queue, msg)

def write_msg(queue, msg, callback=None):
    yield queue.write(msg, callback=callback)  # This has to do non-blocking I/O.
```

In this example, `queue.write` would need to be some API that sends your request using non-blocking I/O, and executes `callback` when a response is received. Without knowing exactly what `queue` in your original example is, I can't specify exactly how that can be implemented in your case.

Edit: Assuming you're using `boto`, you may want to check out [`bototornado`](https://github.com/yyuu/botornado), which implements [the exact same API I described above](https://github.com/yyuu/botornado/blob/master/botornado/sqs/queue.py#L154):

```
def write(self, message, callback=None):
    """
    Add a single message to the queue.
    :type message: Message
    :param message: The message to be written to the queue
    :rtype: :class:`boto.sqs.message.Message`
    :return: The :class:`boto.sqs.message.Message` object that was written.
```

Comment: Ok, so it seems that main problem is that the function executed by the  task has to be non-blocking. By the way I wasn't aware of bototornado, which seems to be the solution to my problem

Comment: @user1030148 Right. Unlike using threads or something like `gevent`, the conversion from synchronous to asynchronous usually doesn't happen in `tornado` without you re-writing your existing code to some degree.

Comment: Finally I used the module you wrote about (botornado). However, while I was looking for alternatives I found this interesting  [article](http://blog.joshhaas.com/2011/06/marrying-boto-to-tornado-greenlets-bring-them-together/). It might be useful for someone else who is struggling with tornado and bodo